# setText to an EditText from a string

Tags: android, android-edittext

I was trying to assign some text on my object inside an EditText. It returns some runtime exception. myObj.address has values and I am able to toast it by getAddress.toString().

```
         my_edittext = (EditText).findViewById(R.id.myedittext);
         my_edittext.setText(myObj.getAddress().toString());
```

How do I set this text inside my EditText? I doubt if .setText only accepts charSequence, then how do I convert my string to charSequnce ?

**Edit: my Logcat here**

```
10-19 13:58:40.719: D/AndroidRuntime(4344): Shutting down VM
10-19 13:58:40.719: W/dalvikvm(4344): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a0d1f8)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at com.x.y.z.activity.NewEntryActivity$3.onClick(NewEntryActivity.java:677)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14105)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
10-19 13:58:40.729: E/AndroidRuntime(4344):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: edittext.setText(myObj.getAddress().toString() + ""); check like this.

Comment: we need your logcat and what is edittext? you declared it as my_edittext.

Comment: Correct this name edittext :)

Comment: what myObj.getAddress() is returning?

Comment: sorry I have edited that, it is my_edittext.settext , myObj.getAddress.toString will return a string value , and it is working if i toast it.

Comment: please post stacktrace !!! because it will work even if you write it as you wrote in question

Comment: I have updated the question with logcat

Comment: can you post your onClick method?

Comment: it is ` my_edittext.setText(myObj.getAddress().toString()); `

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18278/discussion-between-pratik-and-lena)

Answer (score 1):

I think it should be

```
my_edittext.setText(myObj.getAddress().toString());
```

Comment: it is not working, already my code is like that. ( i put a wrong code on question and just now edited that )